# Query won't convert a nvarchar(30) to a decimal

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query, that when it is run gives the following error:

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '247.300' to data type int.
```

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT UD.SerialNumber,
       UD.ReadingDate,
       UD.ChannelName,
       CONVERT(decimal(18,2), ChannelValue) - LAG(CONVERT(decimal(18,2), ChannelValue),1,
       CONVERT(decimal(18,2), ChannelValue)) OVER (PARTITION BY ChannelName, 
       CASE ChannelValue WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ORDER BY ReadingDate ASC)
FROM [Staging].[UriData] UD
WHERE UD.ChannelName IN (SELECT ChannelName FROM [Staging].[ActiveChannels])
ORDER BY ReadingDate;
```

Here is a fiddle: [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d2133169eb543680745a27dd09d90899)

The only difference between the fiddle (which works fine) and the query here is that I have to have the `ChannelValue` column `NVARCHAR` as some of the data will be in text. I have filtered out all of the text data in the query.

I have also tested it with the following query and the data doesn't show up. If it wasn't a number I would expect it to appear here.

```
select ChannelValue
from [Staging].[UriData]
where try_convert(numeric(18, 2), ChannelValue) is null and ChannelValue is not null;
```

The expected outcome is that the number '247.300' is converted into a number and processed. Why won't it convert?

Comment: Because, if you Read The Error, you can't convert that value to an INT......

Comment: *"I have to have the ChannelValue column NVARCHAR as some of the data will be in text"*. How do you apply the expression I provided in your other question to a "textual" data. For example `'2831.02' - 'test' = ???`. If you need to store textual data, do so in a different column; don't mix and match data (and especially don't store data you need to apply mathematical operations to as an `nvarchar`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the error message it complains about `int`.

this is from the implicit cast here

```
CASE ChannelValue WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Use an explicit cast

```
 CASE CONVERT(decimal(19,3), ChannelValue) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

then values such as `247.300` will convert fine and be comparable to the integer `0`.

Though you also say "I have filtered out all of the text data in the query.". In that case you should always use `TRY_CONVERT` anyway in case operations get ordered such that the conversion happens before the filter.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot easily filter out text values in SQL Server -- the database reserves the right to re-arrange operations and this might cause an error.

So, use `TRY_CONVERT()`:

```
SELECT UD.SerialNumber,
       UD.ReadingDate,
       UD.ChannelName,
       (TRY_CONVERT(decimal(18, 2), ChannelValue) -
        TRY_CONVERT(DECIMAL(18, 2), LAG(ChannelValue), 1, ChannelValue) OVER (PARTITION BY ChannelName, CASE ChannelValue WHEN '0' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ORDER BY ReadingDate ASC))
       )
FROM [Staging].[UriData] UD
WHERE UD.ChannelName IN (SELECT ChannelName
                         FROM [Staging].[ActiveChannels]
                        )
ORDER BY ReadingDate;
```

If `ChannelValue` is a string, then the comparison in the `CASE` should be to a string value.

Under most circumstances, you would only need to do the conversion once.  However, to avoid a problem with the subtraction, you also have to convert before the subtraction.

You can use this logic to simplify:

```
SELECT UD.SerialNumber,
       UD.ReadingDate,
       UD.ChannelName,
       (ChannelValue_d -
        LAG(ChannelValue_d), 1, ChannelValue_d) OVER (PARTITION BY ChannelName, CASE ChannelValue WHEN '0' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ORDER BY ReadingDate ASC)
       )
FROM [Staging].[UriData] UD CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (TRY_CONVERT(decimal(18, 2), ChannelValue) )
     ) v(ChannelValue_d)
WHERE UD.ChannelName IN (SELECT ChannelName
                         FROM [Staging].[ActiveChannels]
                        )
ORDER BY ReadingDate;
```

Comment: this has not fixed the part that is actually causing the problem. The error is about the value '247.300' to data type int

Comment: @MartinSmith . . . I see.  I was a little confused by your answer.  I thought maybe the OP had changed the question at some point.